# Applying map and/or lambda function on a particular column of np array

Tags: python, numpy

I have, for example, this NumPy array whose element are different types:

```
x = np.array([[123, '()', 34], [5, '(3,4,5)', 100]])
```

My goal is to decode a particular column in the array, so for example I want to apply map function to the second column to tuple. The expected output is:

```
x = np.array([[123, (), 34], [5, (3,4,5), 100]])
```

How to do that with map or lambda function? Thanks

Comment: So the middle element is always a string representing a tuple?

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] showing code for your most recent try

Comment: not always in the middle, the function will have the column number as argument. Basically the question is how to apply map or lambda in a particular column of np array?

Comment: An object dtype array is essentially a list, or this case, a list of lists.  Ordinary list iteration or list comprehension, or if you prefer list map, can be used.  This isn't a `numpy` task.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy arrays to hold objects is not necessarily efficient, but anyway you could use the following:

```
x = np.array([[123, '()', 34], [5, '(3,4,5)', 100]], dtype=object)
from ast import literal_eval
x[:, 1] = list(map(literal_eval, x[:, 1]))
```

*NB. note that you **need** to have an object type for this to work*

output:

```
array([[123, (), 34],
       [5, (3, 4, 5), 100]], dtype=object
```